# SQL subquery using ORDER BY and LIMIT in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to write this query in SQLAlchemy language.

```
SELECT * FROM Servers where Servers.protocol='TCP' and (
1=(SELECT status FROM Status WHERE Servers_ip = Servers.ip AND Servers_port = Servers.port ORDER BY timestamp desc LIMIT 1) OR 
4=(SELECT status FROM Status WHERE Servers_ip = Servers.ip AND Servers_port = Servers.port ORDER BY timestamp desc LIMIT 1)
)
```

I have an class Servers and a class Status with the attributes of the tables.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You've got to put those subselects into another one to get a derived table. Otherwise LIMIT in subqueries won't work. That should do it:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Servers 
where Servers.protocol='TCP' and (
1=(
    SELECT s.status FROM (
        SELECT status 
        FROM Status 
        WHERE Servers_ip = Servers.ip AND Servers_port = Servers.port 
        ORDER BY timestamp desc 
        LIMIT 1
    ) s 
  ) 
OR 
4=(
    SELECT t.status FROM (
        SELECT status 
        FROM Status 
        WHERE Servers_ip = Servers.ip AND Servers_port = Servers.port 
        ORDER BY timestamp desc 
        LIMIT 1
    ) t
  ) 
);
```